# prevent period intersection in concurrent insert

Tags: java, sql, db2

I have a table with fields: name|...|start_date|end_date

My code now is:

```
select .... 'check for period intersection
insert .... 'if check succesfull insert new row
```

This code in one transaction.
When two users try to insert new record in the same time with same fields(and periods intersects) two records inserted. 
But I want to avoid that inserting. First user must insert, other user must get conflict. 
How can I do it ?

P.S. I use IBM DB2

Answer (score 0):

You could use an UK or select for update:

```
select .... 'check for period intersection FOR UPDATE WITH RS USE AND KEEP UPDATE LOCKS
```

Update:
Try locking the whole table before the select with:

```
LOCK TABLE TABLE_NAME IN EXCLUSIVE MODE
```

This way, the second transaction waits for the previous one to commit before select. The  EXCLUSIVE MODE locks the select statements too, not only updates and inserts.

Update 2:
If "check for period intersection" uses only column from the same table as the one you're inserting into, then instead of select add a constraint check to your table. See http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc%2Fdoc%2Ft0004984.htm

Comment: I can't use unique key, because I check for intersection, dates can be different.

Comment: Assume my table is empty. Two users try to insert records in same time(01.01.2012-31.01.2012 and 15.01.2012-31.01.2012). What happens if I'll use FOR UPDATE ?

Comment: @nkislitsin I think you need to lock the table. No need to select for update in this case.

Comment: do you know other variants without locking ?

Comment: @nkislitsin I updated the answer. I'm running out of ideas :)

Answer (score 0):

Insert query which gets the data from select. In select the values selected will data that need to be inserted. The where clause can check for condition and should return null if check fails. So if I want to enter if id 5 is not in in table than

```
  Insert into test1(val) select "test" from (select case when id = 5 then null else 5 end '1' from sysP where id =5) aa
```

This query will insert *test* in table test1 is id =5 is not there in sysP table

Comment: I want to use with NOT EXISTS

Comment: Any specific reason for using not exists.

Comment: insert into ... select ... where not exists(select ...). I think is suitable for me.

Comment: In case of not exists, each row of outer table will be checked against the inner query. try using sysibm.sysdummy1 in outer table and your check query innner part. I don't have DB2 available to test this.

Comment: Try this. Assuming that 5 is in table this will not return any thing. For id which are not in table will give you *test*      select "test"
from (select 1 id from sysibm.sysdummy1) s1 
where not exists (
          select * from         
          sysP s2     
          where s2.id = 5 ) 
go

Comment: Sorry, depending on lock-levels, this will _not_ guarantee the desired behavior in a highly concurrent environment.

Comment: @X-Zero - Can you pls explain or point to resource where this is explained.

Comment: Think about this - what happens if two processes run that statement at (effectively) the exact same time?  If you don't lock the _entire_ table, you get two instances of `'test'` in `test1` (or one, and a process with an error, if there's a constraint).  When dealing with a multi-user environment, **always** ask 'what happens if two (or more!) people do this at the same time?'.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like [`MERGE`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0010873.html) is exactly what you want, when combined with some error raising.  I'm assuming you're using DB2 on Linux/Unix/Windows, but `MERGE` has been on the Mainframe DB2 since v9.1 as well.

```
MERGE INTO YOUR_TABLE YT
USING (
        VALUES ('val1', 'val2', 'val3')
    ) MG(v1, v2, v3)
 ON (TY.v1 = MG.v1)
WHEN MATCHED 
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '70001'
    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Record already exists!'
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
   INSERT(v1, v2, v3)
   VALUES(MG.v1, MG.v2, MG.v3
ELSE IGNORE;
```

The `USING` clause can be used with provided values (like I have here), or it could be a sub-select.  There are other examples on the Merge page on the Information Center that I linked above.